# How can I stop the rot of window?

Tags: wood, windows, dry-rot

I've chipped away at all the very rotten parts. Is there a sealant I can apply that will stop further rot?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're not ready for sealer yet. Get a chisel and get rid of all that loose wood, then sand it smooth, do the whole sill. Then get some wood filler and fill in any deep spots where the horizontal meets the vertical and any other low spot. Sand it again. Now check out what types of sealers you can get at your home store. There are many so read the directions and have at it.

Comment: +1. I like the 2 part wood consolidators (like Abatron) prior to wood filler. As noted, read the instructions on the Abatron and don’t mix it in a plastic cup.

Comment: If the damage is bad enough, there are epoxy putties that can be used to rebuild it as a kludge alternative to replacing the piece. I had good luck with one of the "kneed to mix" putties, less good luck with one sold in two separate cans;  on a hot day the latter, mixed as directed, was curing so quickly that it was hard to apply. (Unfortunately I don't remember the brand.)